# Checking the type in GHCi gives weird output, why?

Tags: haskell, ghci

On running the following in GHCi:

```
:t 1:2
```

I get as output:

`(Num [a], Num a) => [a]`

While, running the following:

```
:t 'a':'b'
```

Gives me an error.

Personally, i fell that it should be a type error, but in case of `Num` that's not the case. Can anyone explain what's happening here?

---

What I mean is that, of course it shouldn't work, but ***checking the type*** in the `Num` case gives a result while in case of `Char` it gives an error.

Comment: @leftaroundabout This is really non-obvious duplicate...

Comment: @EugeneSh. you're right, this wasn't a very good match. I added a better one to the duplicates-list, we could certainly find more yet. The essential issue has been asked about plenty of times already, so I really rather wouldn't keep this question open.

Comment: Also compare `:t 1` to `:t 'a'`, and look at `:t 1 + 2`.  Then try `:t (1::Int):2`.

Comment: So @molbdnilo, basically, the reason that we get no error with `Num` case is because its a typeclass and we can have some type in the numeric hierarchy with the given type while `Char` is a specific type and here the system knows its wrong to say `'a':'b'` that's why it gave that error, right?

Comment: Yeah, something like that, I think. (I'm not an expert). *If* you had a type `a` such that both `a` and `[a]` were instances of `Num`, the first would be valid. (Note that `1` and `2` have different types in `1:2`. Mysterious creature, that Haskell.)